# File sending (large) using Socket Programming

Tags: java, sockets

I was wondering if I could get some guidance to solving my problem...

You see I'm trying to get my hands on Socket programming; I managed to create a client and server; the server writes to the client no problem;
I've even manage to send files using

```
byte [] mybytearray  = new byte [(int)myFile.length()];
  FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
```

That on the server side.
On the client side

```
byte [] mybytearray  = new byte [filesize];
InputStream is = sock.getInputStream();
FileOutputStream fileos = new FileOutputStream("Filename.dat");
BufferedOutputStream bufferos = new BufferedOutputStream(fileos);
bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
current = bytesRead;


do {
   bytesRead =
      is.read(mybytearray, current, (mybytearray.length-current));
   if(bytesRead >= 0) current += bytesRead;
} while(bytesRead > -1);

bufferos.write(mybytearray, 0 , current);
bufferos.flush();
long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println(end-start);
bufferos.close();
```

My question comes to I'm not able to send large files; I keep on getting 
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space"

Any thoughts or directions to how I can manage sending large files to the client from server? I mean sizes of say 600 MB or so....
any thought?
Highly appreciated ... thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, your heap is currently having to try to hold 'mybytearray', which is the size of the file you're trying to receive (presumably). You need to move the bos.write() operation to within the loop, and make 'mybytearray' a fixed size.  Here's an example of copying one stream to another that doesn't really care about the size of the data being streamed:

```
    public static void stream(InputStream in, OutputStream out)
        throws IOException {
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    int bytesRead = 0;

    try {

        while (-1 != (bytesRead = in.read(buf, 0, buf.length))) {
            out.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("Error with streaming op: " + e.getMessage());
        throw (e);
    } finally {
                    try{
           in.close();
           out.flush();
           out.close();
                    } catch (Exception e){}//Ignore
    }
}
```

Comment: If an IOException occurs then both the InputStream and OutputStream are left open.  Probably better to close these (swallowing exceptions) in a finally block.

Comment: P.S. There are probably third party libraries that deal with this but I typically implement a utility method: IOUtil.closeIgnoringExceptions(Closeable... closeables) to perform this step and avoid the need for a second nested try...finally within the first finally block.  The utility method should handle null references to avoid cases where one of the streams threw an exception during creation.

Comment: worked like a charm; I've applied basing on your example the solution and worked like a charm...thank you all...

Answer (score 4):

You are running out of memory because you are allocating `mybytearray` to have a length of `filesize`.  One possible solution is to invoke the JVM with a larger heap; e.g. `-Xmx1G`.

However, another point is whether you need to read the entire file into memory - On the server side this definitely **is not** the case: You can simply read the file in chunks into a **fixed size array** and then write these chunks to the output stream.  That way your server's memory footprint will not increase when it attempts to send large files back to the client.

Comment: Yes - absolutely just read in reasonable-sized chunks and send those. Chunks of 512kb would be more than sufficient. Even if you increased the heap size, if the file you're sending approaches the size of the heap (but doesn't exceed it), but you want this server to be able to serve multiple, simultaneous connections, then as soon as you open a second large file, you're going to run into the same problem.

Comment: Increasing heap size is a terrible solution to this problem

Comment: @normalocity: Agreed; my point regarding the heap size was more for the client-side where the client is attempting to read the file from the server into an array.

Comment: @Mick: Did you completely ignore the second paragraph?

Comment: @Adamski - Yeah, understood - I completely support your answer. My point was more for the benefit of ibininja

Comment: See my stream method example below.  InputStream in and OutputStream out can be a FileInputStream of a ByteArrayInputStream, etc.  You will only hit problems with memory using this if you use a stream that is memory-bounded, like bytearray streams.  This applies both to client and server.

Comment: I see; I guess to send the file in chunks is the best approach; does this has to do with serialization? can you guide me to where I can read about partitioning the large file before sending it? thank you

Comment: It's unrelated to serialization.  To partition you simply need to loop, reading from the InputStream into an array (see Mick Sear's solution).

Comment: @Adamski: Sure.  It's just that you mentioned it as a solution, when it's really not a solution.  I agree with your second paragraph.

Comment: @Mick: It's a solution in cases where on the receiving end the aim is not to write the file immediately to disk but to process it in memory some how.  I agree that the chunking solution is the idiomatic way to send the data.

Answer (score 3):

Don't read the complete file into RAM in order to send, but send the file chunkwise.

```
byte [] mybytearray  = new byte [(int)myFile.length()];
```

is bad if `(int)myFile.length()` is more than fits in memory.

Instead, use

```
byte [] buffer= new byte[4096];
```

or so and make a loop, reading from file and sending to socket.

Comment: Thank you; currently looking into how to sending the file in chunks

Answer (score -2):

It means JVM ran out of memory.. So you should basically increase JVM heap space.. So I think problem is not about sending large files..

Comment: -1 because there are better ways of doing this.  He will always run out memory if he sends a file bigger than heap space with his current solution.

Comment: yeap you're right, the solutions which others suggest, It's fat better.. Dividing large files int fixed size memory array is making more sense :)